# Power path PCB design

Tags: mosfet, charging, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm using a TP4056 Li-Ion battery charger with a Raspberry Pi Pico. The charger doesn't have built-in load sharing, so I'm using a P-channel MOSFET to take all load off the battery while it is plugged into USB and charging.

Does this look like it's hooked up right? Specifically the load sharing circuit and the voltage divider that feeds into the ADC channel.

*Schematic*
[image: pi pico gameboy schematic]

*TP4056 Module*
[image]
<sup>Source: https://www.addicore.com/products/tp4056-tc4056a-lithium-battery-charger-and-protection-module</sup>

Comment: When the module is supplied, and when the SW9's A switch is closed the VSYS pin of the RPi will see voltage through the body diode of the MOSFET. Can you give more detail about the application? What is the switch for? How the circuit is intended to work?